# Python Multiprocessing: Extracting a large zip file (~8GB) with many small objects (~5.6 million)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, zip

I have a large zip file of size nearly 8GB, which consists of many (~5.6 million) small files (~1-20 kb) each. I tried extracting this with linux unzip and its too slow. Some other answers suggested other linux packages that could do faster, but I can't install any of those since I don't have sudo access to the machine.

I was wondering if there was a way to use multiple cores in python to do this faster? I am a bit new to this and I checked out another question on the same topic, [(python-parallel-processing-to-unzip-files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43313666/python-parallel-processing-to-unzip-files), but the author mentioned it did not improve the speed.

Anyone have suggestions on what I should do?

Answer (score 2):

Rolling your own unzip code is unlikely to result in improved performance compared to the libraries/programs typically used for that. If there are other programs that you think would unzip the file faster than the standard `unzip` command, you can install them from source without `sudo`. Just build them, but then skip the actual "install" step. The executable for the program should be available locally in some build directory.

Comment: Ok I did not know one could do that without sudo access. Thank you. I will try this out